# How Bootstrap need a size of container into container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would create into section **BODY** of this layout different section row. Is the grid system is resetting to 12 in this area or is 9?
If I need to create into **BODY** section 12 column can I do? or not?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">SX BAR</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">BODY</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Tnx a lot!

Comment: Are you asking for the number of columns Bootstrap is providing you?

Comment: @Rems: Yes inside BODY area..how many columns max can I use..If I need to genereate other CONTAINER section with different ROWS? 9 or 12?

Comment: `containers` contains `rows` which can contain up to 12 columns. If you put 12 columns in a row, and you build another row just after, it won't be affected by the number of columns in the previous row. So it will be basically 12. So, if you build antoher container, then you'll have to build another row in it, and thus the number will still be 12. Please, read carefully [Bootstrap CSS Specifications](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) because you seem to have misunderstood the concept of Bootstrap "Grid".

Comment: @Rems: tnx you very much

Comment: Let me copy that as a proper response. :)

Comment: @DanielleGrillo If my answer helped you, I would really appreciate that you accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`containers` contains `rows` which can contain up to 12 columns.

If you put 12 columns in a `row`, and you build another `row` just after, it won't be affected by the number of columns in the previous `row`. So it will be basically 12.

So, if you build antoher `container` after the first one, then you'll have to build another `row` in it, and thus the number will still be 12.

I would advise you to read carefully [Bootstrap CSS Grid System Doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) because you seem to have misunderstood the concept of Bootstrap "Grid".